# Propulsion of a spacecraft

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism, forces, rocket-science, propulsion

If a craft is positioned at the strongest point of the earth's electromagnetic field being either positive or negative and the craft activates the same field it would repel each other would it create trust and what speed would the repel be

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Physics SE. The less famous [Space SE](https://space.stackexchange.com) is a good place for questions about space travel.

Answer (score 1):

The earth's magnetic field is very weak. Any electromagnet set up in opposition to it would need to be immense in order to produce any measurable repulsion, and the power source needed to drive it would be even more immense.

This would make the spacecraft containing the electromagnet and the power supply extremely heavy, and that renders your proposition completely impractical.